# PHP - “Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference”

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente clase de PHP

```
<?php
class __lovie{
    private $ms;
    private static $i;
    private $llave;

    private function setKey(){
        $this->llave = '#$/($=';
    }

    public function __construct(){
        try {
            $g = parse_ini_file(__DIR__."/set/conf.ini.php");
            $this->ms = new PDO("mysql:host={$g['HST']};dbname={$g['DBN']}","{$g['USR']}","{$g['PWD']}",array(PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
            __lovie::setKey();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    private function crearIdentificacion(){
        $min = 1;
        $max = 0;
        switch(PHP_INT_SIZE) {
            case 4:
                $max = 2147483648;
                break;
            case 8:
                $max = 9223372036854775807;
                break;
            default:
                echo 'PHP_INT_SIZE is ' . PHP_INT_SIZE;
        }
        $diferencia   = bcadd(bcsub($min,$max),1);
        $rand_percent = bcdiv(mt_rand(), mt_getrandmax(), 8);
        return abs(bcadd($min, bcmul($diferencia, $rand_percent, 8), 0));
    }

    private function getLogin($e,$p){
        if (__lovie::ifExists($e,"emailPersona","personas")===true) {
            $querier = $this->ms->prepare("SELECT codePersona FROM personas WHERE emailPersona = :email");
            $querier->bindParam(':email',$e,PDO::PARAM_STR,70);
            $querier->execute();
            $resultado = $querier->fetchAll();
            if (count($resultado) == 1) {
                $tempVal = "";
                foreach ($resultado as $i) {
                    $tempVal = $i['codePersona'];
                }
                $realc = __lovie::desproteger($tempVal);
                if ($realc == $p) {
                    return true;
                }else{
                    $tempVal = null;
                    $realc = null;
                    return "LOG-ERR-CODE";
                }
            }else{
                return 'LOG-ERR-UNKNOWN1';
            }
        }else{
            return "LOG-ERR-EMAIL";
        }
    }

    private function ifExists($value,$columna,$tabla){
        $constructor = "SELECT {$columna} FROM {$tabla} WHERE {$columna} = :valor";
        $querier = $this->ms->prepare($constructor);
        $querier->execute(array(':valor' => $value));
        $resultado = $querier->fetchAll();
        //print_r($resultado);
        if (count($resultado) == 1) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        $querier = null;
    }

    private function proteger($som){
        require_once __DIR__.'/../seguridad/class.php';
        $seguridad = new S(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $seguro = $seguridad->encrypt($som, $this->llave);
        return base64_encode($seguro);
    }

    private function desproteger($som){
        require_once __DIR__.'/../seguridad/class.php';
        $seguro = base64_decode($som);
        $seguridad = new S(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $inseguro = $seguridad->decrypt($seguro, $this->llave);
        return $inseguro;
    }

    public function registroPersona($nombre,$apellido,$email,$password){
        try {
            if(__lovie::ifExists($email,"emailPersona","personas") === true){
                return "REG-ERR1";
            }
            $id = __lovie::crearIdentificacion();
            $cont = 0;
            while (__lovie::ifExists($id,"idPersona","personas") === true) {
                $id = __lovie::crearIdentificacion();
                $cont++;
                if ($cont == 5000) {
                    return "REG-ERR-NOTREACH-ID";
                }
            }
            $code = __lovie::proteger($password);
            $querier = $this->ms->prepare("INSERT INTO personas(idPersona,nomPersona,apePersona,emailPersona,codePersona) VALUES (:id,:nom,:ape,:email,:code)");
            $querier->bindParam(":id",$id);
            $querier->bindParam(":nom",htmlentities($nombre,ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8'),PDO::PARAM_STR,100); //AQUI ES EL ERROR - WARNING.
            $querier->bindParam(":ape",htmlentities($apellido,ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8'),PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
            $querier->bindParam(":email",htmlentities($email,ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8'),PDO::PARAM_STR,70);
            $querier->bindParam(":code",$code);
            if($querier->execute()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function iniciarSesion($email,$password){
        try {
            $g = __lovie::getLogin($email,$password);
            return $g;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

$st = new __lovie();
$f = $st->registroPersona('Janny','Sophia','jsofi@axima.com','12345');
print_r($f);
/*$s = $st->iniciarSesion("jsofia@maximap.com","12345");
print_r($s);*/
?>
```

Mi problema es que, al ejecutar **registroPersona** sale un error de tipo Warning:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/u845134273/public_html/lovie/aplicacion/modelo/class.php on line 135

No comprendo la razón del error. En qué he fallado y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

**Cabe destacar que desde XAMPP funciona correctamente sin advertencias, tengo alojado los archivos en Hostinger actualmente y fue ahí donde empezó a salir ese mensaje.**

### Raro, pero bah!...

En la configuracion de la versión de PHP en Hostinger he cambiado de PHP 5.6 (La predeterminada) a 5.3 y el mensaje no aparece...

Pero de igual modo, necesito trabajar en PHP 5.6

### Por qué no ocultas los mensajes de Warning?

No opto por ello, mi plan no es tapar los errores. Necesito una web totalmente limpia :)

Comment: Exactamente cual es la linea 135

Comment: Entre otras cosas `ifExists` es un método de instancia, no un método estático. Debiera tirarte al menos un E_NOTICE por usarlo de esa manera. Lo mismo pasa con `proteger`y `desproteger`. Son métodos de instancia. Para el error que te da, de todos modos, yo probaría quitando los htmlentities y dejándole a cada `bindParam` la variable tal como viene.

Comment: @MalCam la he marcado con un comentario.

Comment: @amenadiel no comprendo mucho el uso de metodos de instancia y los estaticos. Como puedo solucionar el posible E_NOTICE de *ifExists* pues, esas son funciones que las he escrito segun lo que necesite pero la verdad no sé más sobre el tema :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almacena en una variable el htmlentities.
Y pásale dicha variable al bindParam

```
$nombreEntities = htmlentities($nombre, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$querier->bindParam(":nom", $nombreEntities, PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
```

Hazlo en todos los casos que lo usas.

Comment: Lo voy a probar, +1 por primera respuesta.

Comment: ya nos contarás si te funciona :)

Comment: Sí, sí funciona!